# Show more button not working for my table

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance

I was able to get the show more show less button to work when only using list items. now that i have my list into tables the code doesn't work. it only hides/shows text in the first column.
The Show more button should show the first 10 bullets of both columns then display the button under. when you click the button it also makes text jump positions.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
  var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
  var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read more";
    moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less";
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
```

```css
#more {
  display: none;
}

.columns {
  columns: 2;
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;
  position: relative;
}

.hed {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 800;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 15px 0px 5px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <table width="100%" border="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h4>Elementary</h4>
          <ul>
            <li>Maps: Primary: ELS</li>
            <li>Maps: Primary: Readiness</li>
            <li>Maps: Primary: Outline World Map</li>
            <li>Maps: Intermediate: Physical</li>
            <li>Maps: Intermediate: Political</li>
            <li>Maps: Intermediate: Continents and Oceans Thematic</li>
            <li>Maps: Intermediate: Wealth of Countries Thematic</li>
            <li>Maps: Intermediate: Precipitation Thematic</li>
            <li>Maps: Intermediate: Temperature Thematic</li>
            <li>Maps: Intermediate: Time Zones Thematic</li>
            <span id="dots"></span><span id="more">
  <li>Maps: Intermediate: Land Use Thematic</li>
  <li>Maps: Intermediate: Population Thematic</li>
  <li>Maps: Intermediate: Outline World Map</li>

  <li>State Map</li>
  </ul>
  </td>
  
     <td>
   <h4>Secondary</h4>
   <ul>
   <li>Maps: Intermediate: Physical</li>
   <li>Maps: Intermediate: Political</li>
  <li>Maps: Intermediate: Continents and Oceans Thematic</li>
        <li>Maps: Intermediate: Wealth of Countries Thematic</li>
  <li>Maps: Intermediate: Precipitation Thematic</li>
  <li>Maps: Intermediate: Temperature Thematic</li>
  <li>Maps: Intermediate: Time Zones Thematic</li>
  <li>Maps: Intermediate: Land Use Thematic</li>
  <li>Maps: Intermediate: Population Thematic</li>
  <li>Maps: Intermediate: Outline World Map</li>
  <li>Maps: Secondary: Land Use Thematic</li>
  <li>Maps: Secondary: Population Thematic</li>
 
   </ul>
   </td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
      <td>
  <h4>U.S. History</h4>
  <li>Native Americans</li>
  <li>Spanish Explorers</li>
  <li>Explorers</li>
 </td>
    </tr>
    </span>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">Read more</button>
</body>
```

Comment: the closing tag for <span id="more"> seems to be in a weird place

Answer (score 0):

As the comment above says, there's some pretty screwy HTML there...you can't have random other elements inside a list like that, and you can't have a `<span>` wrapping around the ends of lists, table cells and all sorts. It's not valid HTML. Instead of showing / hiding whole blocks like that, think instead in terms of giving a class to the elements which should be initially hidden, and then removing that class when they need to be shown. Demo:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
  var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");
  var more = document.querySelectorAll(".more");

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    more.forEach(el => el.classList.add("hidden"));
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read more";
  } else {
    more.forEach(el => el.classList.remove("hidden"));
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less";
  }
}
```

```css
#more {
  display: none;
}

.columns {
  columns: 2;
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;
  position: relative;
}

.hed {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 800;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 15px 0px 5px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <table width="100%" border="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h4>Elementary</h4>
          <ul>
            <li>Maps: Primary: ELS</li>
            <li>Maps: Primary: Readiness</li>
            <li>Maps: Primary: Outline World Map</li>
            <li>Maps: Intermediate: Physical</li>
            <li>Maps: Intermediate: Political</li>
            <li>Maps: Intermediate: Continents and Oceans Thematic</li>
            <li>Maps: Intermediate: Wealth of Countries Thematic</li>
            <li>Maps: Intermediate: Precipitation Thematic</li>
            <li>Maps: Intermediate: Temperature Thematic</li>
            <li>Maps: Intermediate: Time Zones Thematic</li>
            <li><span id="dots">...</span></li>
            <li class="more hidden">Maps: Intermediate: Land Use Thematic</li>
            <li class="more hidden">Maps: Intermediate: Population Thematic</li>
            <li class="more hidden">Maps: Intermediate: Outline World Map</li>
            <li class="more hidden">State Map</li>
          </ul>
        </td>

        <td>
          <h4 class="more hidden">Secondary</h4>
          <ul class="more hidden">
            <li>Maps: Intermediate: Physical</li>
            <li>Maps: Intermediate: Political</li>
            <li>Maps: Intermediate: Continents and Oceans Thematic</li>
            <li>Maps: Intermediate: Wealth of Countries Thematic</li>
            <li>Maps: Intermediate: Precipitation Thematic</li>
            <li>Maps: Intermediate: Temperature Thematic</li>
            <li>Maps: Intermediate: Time Zones Thematic</li>
            <li>Maps: Intermediate: Land Use Thematic</li>
            <li>Maps: Intermediate: Population Thematic</li>
            <li>Maps: Intermediate: Outline World Map</li>
            <li>Maps: Secondary: Land Use Thematic</li>
            <li>Maps: Secondary: Population Thematic</li>

          </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h4 class="more hidden">U.S. History</h4>
          <ul class="more hidden">
            <li>Native Americans</li>
            <li>Spanish Explorers</li>
            <li>Explorers</li>
          </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">Read more</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Wowwwwww this is darn near perfect. the only issue is i also need the secondary header and its first 10 bullets to show also.

Comment: Well you can easily move the "more hidden" class definitions around to suit your needs.

Comment: P.s. if the answer has helped you please remember to mark it as "accepted" (by clicking the tick mark next to it so it turns green). Thanks :-)